# PostThreadMessage: Create a message queue

Tags: multithreading, delphi, delphi-10.2-tokyo

I have an issue concerning a Thread lacking a message queue at the begin of its life cycle. MSDN explains

> The thread to which the message is posted must have created a message queue, or else the call to PostThreadMessage fails. Use one of the following methods to handle this situation:
>
> (1) Call PostThreadMessage. If it fails, call the Sleep function and call PostThreadMessage again. Repeat until PostThreadMessage succeeds.
>
> (2) Create an event object, then create the thread. Use the WaitForSingleObject function to wait for the event to be set to the signaled state before calling PostThreadMessage. In the thread to which the message will be posted, call `PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, WM_USER, WM_USER, PM_NOREMOVE)` to force the system to create the message queue. Set the event, to indicate that the thread is ready to receive posted messages.

Method (1) solves my issue, the second call to `PostThreadMethod()` always succeeds in my application.

However, I would like to comprehend the second method and simply don't understand "event object" (certainly not a normal Delphi event?) "to the signalled state" and "set the event to indicate".

QUESTION: Can someone please be so kind as to translate paragraph (2) into a short Delphi code example?

Comment: Note that I removed the second question because at this site it is one question at a time. What's more, the second question would fall foul of the "primarily opinion based" close reason.

Comment: @David: OK, maybe you can shortly comment on whether there are in your opinion better inter-thread communication methods than PostThreadMessage()? I want worker threads to say "started" and "finished" to a managing thread which adds and remove worker threads from a list.

Comment: You certainly don't want to use thread messages. Because they will get lost if you show any modal UI. Using a message only window is the way to do it with messages. As for whether that's the right solution to your problem, I can't say with so little background.

Comment: Hm... all threads involved, i.e. worker threads and managing threads have no UI at all. I thought, threads may not use VCL anyway? Only the main thread has a UI. Is this a problem? It appears to work with TEvent and it did work with repeated first PostMessage, too.

Comment: Often the managing thread is also the UI thread. If you have no UI in any of these threads then perhaps thread message is fine.

Answer (score 5):

These event objects are synchronization objects, described in MSDN here: [Event Objects](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682655.aspx).

At the bottom of that topic is a link to [Using Event Objects](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686915.aspx) which gives example code showing how to create events, set them, wait for them, etc.

In short you use the following functions:

- `CreateEvent` to create the event objects.
- `CloseHandle` to destroy it.
- `SetEvent` and `ResetEvent` to set and reset the event object.
- `WaitForSingleObject` to wait for it to be signaled.

You can use the [`TEvent`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SyncObjs.TEvent) class from the `System.SyncObjs` unit to wrap all of these low-level API calls. Then the process would become like so:

- Create a `TEvent` object, `Event` say, in the reset state.
- Create your worker thread, passing in `Event`.
- Call `Event.WaitFor` in the manager thread to wait for the worker thread to signal that its message queue exists.
- When the worker thread starts executing (i.e. at the start of its `Execute` method), have it create its message queue, and then set the event by calling `Event.SetEvent`.

Comment: Thank you. SyncObjs.TEvent it is. -- Are TEVents restricted to the current process? If several instances of the same application are running, will they see the events of one another or not? Do I have to use instance-unique TEvent names in order to avoid this?

Comment: You can have named events but I don't think the RTL classes wrap that functionality

Comment: TEvent supports "name" and it works for me now. I just don't know whether this name will work inter-instance or is restricted to the current instance.

Comment: Object naming is covered over on MSDN, and yes it used for inter process sync.

Comment: OK, nice to know -- I will restrict myself on using the TEvent object and no name. -- Thanks again for your helpful answer! My application works now as intended and uses one TEvent and PostThreadMessage.

Comment: @HJay you did not say which version of Delphi you are using. Do note that prior to XE8, using a `TEvent` with a blank `Name` [is buggy](https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-9999) in relation to multiple app instances running concurrently. The solution is to patch the RTL, or call `CreateEvent()` directly

Comment: @Remy: I use Delphi Tokyo, but thank for the info. So I can use any dummy name to avoid a blank name? Is it a problem if two instances create a TEvent with the same name?

Comment: One more question: If I have a `TMyThreadPool` with `Event: TEvent` as public field, can I **thread-safe** read TEvent and call `AMyThreadPool.Event.WaitFor` from other threads like AMyWorkerThread if the Event field is only written to once in the constructor of TMyThreadPool?

Comment: Yes, that's no problem.

Comment: @HJay: "*So I can use any dummy name to avoid a blank name?*" - if you do that, a single event object will be shared between multiple app instances, which is what you DON'T want in this situation. The whole point of naming a kernel object such as an event object is to share it across process boundaries. You WANT multiple instances of your app to have their own separate local event objects. Since you are using a fixed version of Delphi, you should be fine using a blank name.