# What's the correct way to bring an asynchronous task back to main thread?

Tags: delphi, asynchronous, shopee

I'm developing a Wrapper for the Shopee API as a Delphi package, it's open source and available on my gh profile. I already ran into a problem similar to this one which was answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78063142/in-delphi-is-it-a-correct-approach-to-free-the-sender-within-an-event?noredirect=1#comment137639250_78063142). But now I can't see the way around anymore.

It starts here:

```pascal
constructor TShopeeContext.Create(AMode, AAPIKey, APartnerID: string);
begin

  if (AMode <> TEST_SHOPEE) and (AMode <> PRODUCTION_SHOPEE_BR) then
    raise Exception.Create('Mode Invalid for Context');

  FHost := AMode;
  FAPI_Key := AAPIKey;
  FPartnerID := APartnerID;

  UpdateInternalConfigFields;

  if FRefreshToken = '' then
    FHasRefreshToken := False
  else
    FHasRefreshToken := True;

  // Checks if the authorization has been granted and is younger than 365 days.
  if (not FAuthorizationGranted) or ((Now - FAuthorizationDate) > 365) then
  begin
    Authorize;
  end;

end;
```

After the `Authorize;` call, any instruction dependent on Authorization Code falls into Undefined Behavior because there's no guarantee I have a code. I would need to wait for Authorize to return before following on. My issue arises from the fact that Authorize creates an object and starts a routine that is Asynchronous, a HTTP listener:

```pascal
procedure TShopeeContext.Authorize;
var
  Authorizator: TShopeeAuthorizator;
begin
  // Request Authorization;
  Authorizator := TShopeeAuthorizator.Create(FHost, FAPI_Key, FPartnerID, 8342);
  try
    Authorizator.AuthorizationRequest;
  finally
    Authorizator.Free;
  end;

end;
```

The `AuthorizationRequest` procedure is implemented as:

```pascal
procedure TShopeeAuthorizator.AuthorizationRequest;
begin
  // Obtem a assinatura da chamada
  FSignature := GetPublicSignString(API_PATH_AUTHORIZATION, FTimestamp);

  // Constroi os parametros
  FRequestParameters.AddItem('partner_id', FPartnerID);
  FRequestParameters.AddItem('timestamp', FTimeStamp);
  FRequestParameters.AddItem('sign', FSignature);
  FRequestParameters.AddItem('redirect', REDIRECT_URL_WS+':'+IntToStr(FPort));

  ShellExecute(0, 'open', PChar(GenerateRequestURL(API_PATH_AUTHORIZATION, FRequestParameters)), nil, nil, SW_SHOWNORMAL);

  FCatcherServer := TCatcherServer.Create();
  FCatcherServer.OnFieldsReady := FieldsReadyHandler;
  FCatcherServer.Listen(FPort);
end;
```

and `FieldsReadyHandler` is the subject of my older question, and the current version is:

```pascal
procedure TShopeeAuthorizator.FieldsReadyHandler(Sender: TObject; Code,
  AuthorizatedID: string);
begin
  // Handle Code, Auth Type and AuthorizatedID.
  FConfigurator := TConfiguratorFile.Create;
  try
    FConfigurator.SaveAuthorizationInfo(Code, AuthorizatedID, (Sender as TCatcherServer).AuthorizationType);
    FSuccess := True;
  finally
    FConfigurator.Free;
  end;

  TThread.Queue(nil, procedure
  begin
    Sender.Free;
  end);
end;
```

Usually it's a matter of HOW to do that, but honestly at this point I'm thinking that I overcomplicated it and don't even know WHAT I should do to overcome this. Anyways, if I were to rewrite I can see my self falling in the same spot where my subsequent tasks depends on the async task to finish. I also tried to add an event to inform the Context that it already obtained the code but (my shot is) it raises access violation because of the way the object is released.

Sorry I can't synthesize a **TL;DR** for this one, but if I had to index my questions the output would be: What is the best approach to this type of problem and how is it handled in pascal? In JS, for example, I would chain infinite `.then()` until the routine doesn't need the async part anymore. I also feel it is going to become a frequent pain if I don't learn to handle it now as requests are asynchronous.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am afraid that your question cannot be easily answered. You will first need to learn about Delphi memory management. Next you will need to learn how to use event handlers in Delphi. Your problems stem from not understanding those concepts well. But you have much bigger issues here. Why are you creating server instance for using what is simple HTTP API? Furthermore, if you need a server, then server is not something that will be created and destroyed on every request. Your design is broken on so many levels that it is impossible to fix it through simple Q/A on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Using forum where people would be able to interactively guide you in right direction would be more appropriate https://en.delphipraxis.net/ is a good place for that.

Comment: Hello! The Server listens for the URI redirect after the Authorization flow in the Shopee Webpage. It exists for this purpose only and that’s why I created it this way: Theoretically, it will only be needed once every 365 days. I’ll post in Delphi Praxis as soon as I get at home. Thanks!

Comment: After Authorize, your code needs to wait for an event which is "set" in FieldsReadyHandler. Check articles and answers about events / the TEvent class, https://stackoverflow.com/a/49610668/80901 for example

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar is usually always very helpful and knowledgeable, but here jumped to a conclusion too quick, I think. The structure is actually sound, and the temporary listening HTTP server (for the returning redirect call) is one of 3 typical ways to handle authentication callbacks (see the 'Loopback URLs' section of https://www.oauth.com/oauth2-servers/oauth-native-apps/redirect-urls-for-native-apps). The more typical case is perhaps where the (interactive) authentication happens in a browser (e.g. built-in TEdgeBrower) and the callback should be caught in the native Delphi code.

Comment: Yeah, indeed. But let me point that I didn't know it was one of the ways to handle URIs. I was asked to make it local and this was the way I found to do it (I'm actually glad that it's not a workaround trick :P). But yeah, the system that originated this library idea is a client w/o server (thus has direct DB access), I wouldn't be able to get and store the code anywhere else. I actually thought it was a poor design choice.

Comment: I was mistaken in my assumption that server is not needed. This does complicates the situation a bit. However, even with server in play, the code is still overly complicated. The solution you got in the answer is a working one, but there are still simpler solutions based solely on event handlers that don't involve events. I will try to post an answer, but I cannot promise I will be able to do that in next few days.

Comment: Actually, an event may still be useful internally, for implementing timeout, if you don't want to allow your software to hang indefinitely waiting for an authorization. But it can be fully encapsulated within the `TShopeeAuthorizator` without being exposed to `TShopeeContext`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reference: [Waiting for a Task to Be Completed](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Alexandria/en/Waiting_for_a_Task_to_Be_Completed)

> To do this, use an event object. Event objects
> (System.SyncObjs.TEvent) should be created with global scope so that
> they can act like signals that are visible to all threads.
> When a thread completes an operation that other threads depend on, it
> calls TEvent.SetEvent. SetEvent turns on the signal, so any other
> thread that checks will know that the operation has completed.

When your authorization is done, **set** the event:

```
procedure TShopeeAuthorizator.FieldsReadyHandler(Sender: TObject; Code,
  AuthorizatedID: string);
begin
  // Handle Code, Auth Type and AuthorizatedID.
  FConfigurator := TConfiguratorFile.Create;
  try
    FConfigurator.SaveAuthorizationInfo(Code, AuthorizatedID, (Sender as TCatcherServer).AuthorizationType);
    FSuccess := True;

    // Notify 
    Event1.SetEvent;

  finally
    FConfigurator.Free;
  end;

  TThread.Queue(nil, procedure
  begin
    Sender.Free;
  end);
end;
```

And in the TShopeeContext, use the Event to **wait** until authorization completed, or a given timeout period elapsed:

```
  if (not FAuthorizationGranted) or ((Now - FAuthorizationDate) > 365) then
  begin
    Event1.ResetEvent; { clear the event before }
    
    Authorize;

    if Event1.WaitFor(20000) <> wrSignaled then
      raise Exception; 
  end;
```

Notes:

- As a minor suggestion, I would not recommend to place the authorization code in the constructor of TShopeeContext. Instead, move it to a separate method, and keep the constructor small so it mainly initializes fields.
- I have not yet used TEvent in my own code. There exist other ways to implement the signalling, which may have advantages over TEvent.

Comment: I didn't test yet but it as I've read from both sources you sent, it is indeed what I'm looking for. One more question tho, the `Event1.WaitFor(20000)` will wait 20 seconds until checking if the state is wrSignaled or will wait UP TO 20 seconds?

Comment: It waits until the state is wrSignaled, but not longer than 20 seconds,